# AWS RDS Concurrent Connections Issue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

So I have an RDS MariaDB server running with the following specs.

- Instance Class: db.m4.2xlarge
- Storage Type: Provisioned IOPS (SSD)
- IOPS: 4000
- Storage: 500 GB

My issue is when the SQL server experience heavy load (connections in excess of 200) it will start to refuse new connections.

However according to the monitoring stats, it should be able to handle connections well above that. At it's peak load these are the following stats:

- CPU Utilization: 18%
- DB Connections: 430
- Write Operations: 175/sec
- Read Operations: 1/sec (This Utilizes MemCache)
- Memory Usage: 1.2GB

The DB has the following hardware specs

- 8 vCPUs
- 32 GB Mem
- 1000 Mbps EBS Optimized

Also from what I can tell RDS has the "Max_Connections" setting in MySQL set to 
2,664.

So I can't understand why it is rejecting new connections at such a low rate by comparison. Is there another setting that controls this either in RDS or in the MariaDB?

Comment: what about IOPS? are you at the limit?

Comment: @Mircea Not even close to the limit, it can handle 4000 IOPS and is averaging around 200.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMariaDBInstance.html Try the: SELECT @@max_connections; and SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`

Comment: What error message do you get when a new connection is rejected?